# How to separate a flex item from another flex item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.innerContainer-1 {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}

.peoples,
.posts {
  list-style: none;
}

.peoples a,
.posts a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.left-side,
.right-side,
.main-container {
  background: #ffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.inner-side,
.news {
  padding: 20px;
}

.left-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-container {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="innerContainer-1">
  <aside class="left-side">

    <div class="inner-side">
      <h2>Popular Posts By.</h2>
      <div class="border2"></div>
      <ul class="peoples">
        <li><a href="">Himanshu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">John doe</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Anjela yu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Brad treversy</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Peter mac</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="news">
      <h2>Latest Post</h2>
      <div class="border2"></div>
      <ul class="posts">
        <li><a href="">Coronavirus</a></li>
        <li><a href="">India Lockdown 3.0</a></li>
        <li><a href="">WHO latest Post</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Work From Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Word's Economy</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Education</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main-container">
      <p> adipisicing elit. Harum, corrupti dolorem sed neque n.</p>
    </div>
```

what i want is whenever i increase the height of aside or main container it will not effect to anothers containers height so that whenever i increase content in any container the relative container will not height himself

Comment: Can you post the css as well?

Comment: there are unpaired closing tags in your HTML

Comment: .innerContainer-1{
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
}

.peoples, .posts{
    list-style: none;
}
.peoples a, .posts a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.left-side, .right-side, .main-container{
    background: #ffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.inner-side, .news{
    padding: 20px;
}
.left-side{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.main-container{
    flex: 2;
}

Comment: @himanXupatHak I made a snippet out of your code ,can you elaborate what you need from looking at the snippet?

Comment: yes where i find?

Comment: i figure this out by myself it is flex start or end